# Listbox of Dataframe "columns" using PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to use PySimpleGUI to create a "drop-down" list of Pandas series that represent columns of an Excel sheet or CSV file (both having headers). This list needs to be updated dynamically based on the input received from sg.FileBrowse such that the user can select from all the available headers/column names. So, for example, if I inputted a file with the following layout, I'd expect to have a drop-down list of "Location","Latitude","Longitude" etc.

[Sample Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxRph.png)

Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: Try `Table` element in PySimpleGUI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.